# How do I use parameter binding with attributes in a C# Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I need a property of my queue message to be the output file name for blob output:

```
public static async Task Run([QueueTrigger("my-queue")] MyClass queueMessage, 
            [Blob("my-storage-container/{queueMessage.MyProperty}", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "my-storage")] Stream output,
            ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken,
            ExecutionContext context)
{
               ...
}
```

I can't find how to do this anywhere in the documentation, and all the documentation is frustratingly for customizing functions.json, which doesn't exist when you develop via code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured this one out. Can't for the life of me find docs on this but you can simply reference properties of the queueMessage in curly braces:

```
public static async Task Run([QueueTrigger("my-queue")] MyClass queueMessage, 
        [Blob("my-storage-container/{MyProperty}", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "my-storage")] Stream output,
        ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken,
        ExecutionContext context)
```

Where MyProperty is a property of MyClass. Note that it can't interpret json on its own for the queue message, you need to explicitly say that the queueMessage is of type MyClass (ie not string or anything else).

Answer (score 1):

After reproducing from my end, I could get this done after following the below steps.

*local.settings.json*

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "ServiceBusConnection": "<YOUR_SERVICEBUS_CONNECTION_STRING>",
    "BlobStorageConnection": "<YOUR_BLOB_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING>"
  }
}
```

Below is something how my *Program.cs* looks like.

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public string queueMessage { get; set; }
    }
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] MyClass queueMessage,
            [Blob("mycontainer/{queueMessage}", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "BlobStorageConnection")] Stream outputBlob, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: queueMessage");
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(outputBlob))
            {
                writer.Write("Hello World!");
            }
        }
    }
```

For demonstration purposes, I'm using the below Json sample.

```
{
    "queueMessage":"QueueMessage.txt"
}
```

[image]

*Results:*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, not quite what I was after as I need a property within queueMessage but I've figured it out and will post below. Appreciate the help :)